# SwiftUI @Observable class ViewModel gets initialized twice when setting an enum variable, but not class ViewModel: ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui, enums, observableobject, observation

Having problems with my ViewModel being initialized twice when using the new Observation framework for my `@Observable class ViewModel`, when setting an enum variable.  Tried changing it back to the older `class ViewModel: ObservableObject` and everything worked as expected.  Does anyone have an explanation?

This example doesn't work.  The `ViewModel.init()` and `AuthManager.init()` get called twice when the `ViewModel.loginStatus` enum is set when using the `@Observable` macro on the `ViewModel`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
   @State private var vm = ViewModel()

   var body: some View {
      Button {
         vm.login()
      } label: {
         Text("Login")
      }
      switch vm.loginStatus {
      case .unknown, .loggedOut:
         Text("Login Screen")
      case .loggedIn:
         Text("Home Screen")
      }
   }
}

-----------------------------------------------

import Foundation
import Observation

@Observable class ViewModel {
   private let auth = AuthManager()

   enum LoginStatus {
      case unknown, loggedIn, loggedOut
   }
   var loginStatus = .unknown

   init() {
      print(#function)
      auth.delegate = self
   }
   
   func login() {
      auth.login()
   }
}

extension ViewModel: AuthManagerDelegate {
   func authStateDidChange(isLoggedIn: Bool) {
      logginStatus = isLoggedIn ? .loggedIn : .loggedOut
   }
}

-----------------------------------------------

protocol AuthManagerDelegate: AnyObject {
   func authStateDidChange(isLoggedIn: Bool)
}

class AuthManager {
   weak var delegate: AuthManagerDelegate?
   private let auth = Dependency()

   init() {
      print(#function)
   }

   var user: User? {
      didSet {
         delegate?.authStateDidChange(isLoggedIn: user != nil)
      }
   }

   func login() {
      auth.signIn { [weak self] result in
         guard let self else { return }
         user = result.user
      }
   }
}
```

However, when converting this back to the old way before using the `@Observable` macro, the `ViewModel.init()` and `AuthManager.init()` only get called once as expected:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()

   var body: some View {
      ...same as above...
   }
}

-----------------------------------------------

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   private let auth = AuthManager()

   enum LoginStatus {
      case unknown, loggedIn, loggedOut
   }
   @Published var loginStatus = .unknown

   ini() {
      print(#function)
      auth.delegate = self
   }

   func login() {
      auth.login()
   }
}

extension ViewModel: AuthManagerDelegate {
   func authStateDidChange(isLoggedIn: Bool) {
      logginStatus = isLoggedIn ? .loggedIn : .loggedOut
   }
}

-----------------------------------------------

protocol AuthManagerDelegate: AnyObject {
   ...same as above...
}

class AuthManager {
   ...same as above...
}
```

Comment: You don't need `@State` for your view model unless you pass it as an environment. Don't know if your problem is caused by that, or something else, but try

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  In the real project it does actually get passed in as an environment object using `.environment(vm)`.  No problems if I use `ObservableObject` and pass it using `.environmentObject(vm)`.  I doubled checked Apple's documentation to make sure I'm using the new framework correctly.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

Comment: Use `View` as your view model, use `@State` for read/write data.

Comment: What do you mean by use `View` as the view model?  Do you suggest me creating an `@State var loginStatus = LoginStatus.unknown` to see if I can read / write properly within the View itself?

Answer (score 0):

It is an unfortunate accident of history (I believe) that [the `State` initializer has this signature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/init(wrappedvalue:)):

```
init(wrappedValue value: Value)
```

while [the `StateObject` initializer has this signature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject/init(wrappedvalue:)):

```
init(wrappedValue thunk: @autoclosure @escaping () -> ObjectType)
```

Notice that `StateObject` takes an `@autoclosure`, while `State` does not.

So each time your program creates an instance of your old-style (`StateObject`-based) `ContentView`, it initializes the `StateObject`-wrapped `vm` property with a closure that calls the `ViewModel` initializer. SwiftUI only then calls that closure one time, the first time the `ContentView` appears in your view hierarchy. On subsequent updates, it reuses the already-created `ViewModel` instead of calling the closure to create another.

But each time your program creates an instance of your new-style (`Observation`-based) `ContentView`, it initializes the `State`-wrapped `vm` property with a newly created `ViewModel`. Then, on updates, SwiftUI discards the new `ViewModel` in favor of the old one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for sharing the documentation.  I see in the `@State` wrapper, it says, "SwiftUI initializes the state’s storage only once for each container instance that you declare...On the other hand, each instance of MyView creates a distinct instance of the state."  It sounds like `@State` variables get recreated when the `View` is being re-drawn?  In that case, `@State` view models would also get recreated?  If so, then why use `@Observable class` view models?  Should we just stick with `ObservableObject` for view models?